# Select mismatched columns and values from two exactly similar pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to select the mismatched columns and their values from two exactly similar dataframes.

```
import pandas as pd

list1 = [['a', 'key1', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['w', 'key2', 'x',   'y', 'z']] 

list2 = [['a', 'key1', 'b', 'p', 'q'], ['w', 'key2', 'x',   'y', 'z'], ['w', 'key3', 'i', 'j', 'k']] 
  
# creating df object with columns specified    
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list1, columns =['col_1', 'key_col', 'col_2', 'col_3', 'col_4']) 
print(df1.to_string())
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list2, columns =['col_1', 'key_col', 'col_2', 'col_3', 'col_4']) 
print(df2.to_string())
```

**What I have now:**

| col_1 | key_col | col_2 | col_3 | col_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | key1 | b | c | d |
| w | key2 | x | y | z |

| col_1 | key_col | col_2 | col_3 | col_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | key1 | b | p | q |
| w | key2 | x | y | z |
| w | key3 | i | j | k |

I have 2 dataframes with same schema from different data sources.

**What I want:**

Join (outer join) the 2 dataframes using the "key_col" as the join key and give the output in the following format:

For each row of the table obtained after the join, return the following row:

| key_col | mismatched_column_names | mismatched_values_in_first_df | mismatched_values_in_second_df |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| key1 | [col3, col4] | [c, d] | [p, q] |
| key3 | [col1, col2, col3, col4] | [None, None, None, None] | [w, i, j, k] |

I am looking for the query to do so in pandas.

Comment: please provide the DataFrame constructors of your inputs

Comment: Didn't get you. Are you asking how the input DFs are created? It would be something like pd.DataFrame({2d_array}, {schema}). @mozway

Comment: I just ask if you can provide the `df = pd.DataFrame(...)` code in your question, this makes it easier to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Added the constructors. Can you please help me with the query? Thanks. @mozway

Comment: Thanks @Rahul I provided an answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option:

```
# align the DataFrames
idx = pd.concat([df1['key_col'], df2['key_col']]).unique()

d1 = df1.set_index('key_col').reindex(idx)
d2 = df2.set_index('key_col').reindex(idx)

# get mask for different values
m = d1.ne(d2).stack()

# compute the output
out = pd.DataFrame(
  {'mismatched_column_names': m.reset_index(1).loc[m.values, 'level_1'].groupby(level=0).agg(list),
   'mismatched_values_in_first_df': d1.stack(dropna=False)[m].droplevel(1).groupby(level=0).agg(list),
   'mismatched_values_in_second_df': d2.stack(dropna=False)[m].droplevel(1).groupby(level=0).agg(list)}
).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  key_col       mismatched_column_names mismatched_values_in_first_df mismatched_values_in_second_df
0    key1                [col_3, col_4]                        [c, d]                         [p, q]
1    key3  [col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4]          [nan, nan, nan, nan]                   [w, i, j, k]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. Just one question though. How can we compute this if we had a composite key (key_col1, key_col2) instead of primary key (key_col)?

Comment: Use a MultiIndex ;)

Answer (score 0):

So setting up the problem as per your example gives us

```
import pandas as pd

list1 = [['a', 'key1', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['w', 'key2', 'x',   'y', 'z']] 

list2 = [['a', 'key1', 'b', 'p', 'q'], ['w', 'key2', 'x',   'y', 'z'], ['w', 'key3', 'i', 'j', 'k']] 
  
# creating df object with columns specified    
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list1, columns =['col_1', 'key_col', 'col_2', 'col_3', 'col_4']) 
print(df1.to_string())
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list2, columns =['col_1', 'key_col', 'col_2', 'col_3', 'col_4']) 
print(df2.to_string())
```

this

```
  col_1 key_col col_2 col_3 col_4
0     a    key1     b     c     d
1     w    key2     x     y     z
  col_1 key_col col_2 col_3 col_4
0     a    key1     b     p     q
1     w    key2     x     y     z
2     w    key3     i     j     k
```

now looking at an outer merge

```
m = df1.merge(df2, on='key_col', how='outer', suffixes=['df1', 'df2'], indicator=True)
```

will give you this

```
col_1df1    key_col col_2df1    col_3df1    col_4df1    col_1df2    col_2df2    col_3df2    col_4df2    _merge
0   a   key1    b   c   d   a   b   p   q   both
1   w   key2    x   y   z   w   x   y   z   both
2   NaN key3    NaN NaN NaN w   i   j   k   right_only
```

now extracting the differences are just a run through the columns...

Comment: "now extracting the differences are just a run through the columns..." This is where I am stuck. I am looking for the query to get the output in the expected format given in the question.